# .htaccess редирект

Tags: php, .htaccess

Случайно сделал редирект на несуществующий сайт, не могу зайти в админку, может кто-нибудь помочь? Глупо получилось

Comment: ну и естественно ошибка 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

nginx/1.9.9

Comment: А подправить htacess через ftp или что там хостер для доступа предоставляет

Comment: Спасибо, вот сам допер, что через ftp можно, но не получается, скачал sublime установил ftp соединение, но не коннектится

Comment: скачай фаил, поправь залей обратно

Comment: схему я понял, не могу зайти на сервер пароль и имя хоста ввел, не получается законнектиться

Comment: админка полетела, не знаю что делать

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо запросить у хостера адрес сервера к которому вы подключаетесь; порт (обычно это 21); логин и пароль.

Лучше поспользуйтесь filezilla, она хотя бы подскажет, какая ошибка. Саблайм, к сожалению, ошибок не показывает.

Кстати, в качестве теста, вы можете авторизоваться на сервере с помощью Google Chrome. Только надо не http(s):// протокол использовать, а ftp:// логин и пароль браузер сам запросит.

Если что-то не подходит для авторизации свяжитесь с техподдержкой хостинга и запросите сброс пароля с последующей отправкой новых данных вам на электронную почту.

Comment: Пароль нашли, теперь другие проблемы,
Всем большое спасибо за помощь )